# Foreign key referring to multiple rows in another table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am working with MySQL, trying to build an online vehicles database system. For this purpose, I created two tables: vehicles and owners.

```
create table vehicles
(
  v_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  v_reg_number varchar(255) unique,
  v_engine_number varchar(255) unique,
  v_chassis_number varchar(255) unique,
  v_type varchar(255),
  v_manufacturer varchar(255),
  v_model_year varchar(255),
  v_power varchar(255),
  v_origin varchar(255) 
)

create table owners
(
  o_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  v_id int,
  o_name varchar(255),
  o_father_name varchar(255),
  o_cnic varchar(255) unique,
  o_dob varchar(255),
  o_gender varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY(v_id) REFERENCES vehicles(v_id)
)
```

So one owner may have more vehicles registered in his name. My question is how can multiple IDs, referring to the `vehicles` table, be saved in `owners.v_id`?

Comment: A foreign key must satisfy a single row. And your data ought not to have CSV data jammed insane in it denormalized and multi-value. Step back and think about what you are trying to accomplish without producing a horrible system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual solution to this would be to create an intersection table:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles_owned
(
  o_id INT,
  v_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (o_id, v_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (o_id)
    REFERENCES owners (o_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (v_id)
    REFERENCES vehicles (v_id)
);
```

You then drop `v_id` from `owners`.

This table allows each `owner` to own multiple `vehicles`, and each `vehicle` to have multiple `owners`. If you want to enforce a one-owner-per-vehicle constraint, add a **`UNIQUE`** index to `vehicles_owned.v_id`.

EDIT: Of course, if you want to enforce a one-owner-per-vehicle constraint, you could also simply add `o_id` to `vehicles` as a foreign key, and not bother with the intersection table.