# SQL: several foreign keys stored in a row

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to create a database listing sample characteristics and tests done on these samples. I have two tables, `samples` and `tests` with `ID` and `TESTID` as primary keys.

An unknown number of tests can be performed on each sample and I would like to store the `TESTID` of the tests performed as foreign keys in the `TESTS` column of the `samples` table.

I checked several questions ([Foreign key referring to multiple rows in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825685/foreign-key-referring-to-multiple-rows-in-another-table) and [MySQL, select multiple rows as one based on foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266428/mysql-select-multiple-rows-as-one-based-on-foreign-key)). From what I understood, I cannot store several values in a given column of a row but I do not understand how else to proceed.

Can someone explain how to obtain a result equivalent to what is shown below?

```
samples:
| ID | NAME | TESTS    |
|----|------|----------|
|  0 | S_0  | T0,T1    |
|  1 | S_1  | T0,T2    |
|  2 | S_2  | T3,T4,T5 |

tests:
| TESTID |      TEST  |
|--------|------------|
|     T0 |     test 0 |
|     T1 |     test 1 |
|     T2 |     test 2 |
|     T3 |     test 3 |
|     T4 |     test 4 |
|     T5 |     test 5 |
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: This is just to show what I am trying to do. My question is that I don't know how else to store these multiple `TESTID` data for each sample.

Comment: On the Samples table, individually list each testID on its own line for a given sample.

Comment: Okay. In that case, how do I avoid multiple primary keys for each sample? Wouldn't a new line mean a new primary key? Then, if I refer to a sample by its primary key in a further table, how would I get all instances corresponding to this sample.

Comment: @AlMa Use samples_tests table which contains sample ID and the TESTID. One row for each pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding multiple value separated by comma or hyphen in a single column is generally not a good idea. You could use a Composite Primary Key on a new "relation" table

```
CREATE TABLE samples (
  id INT,
  name VARCGAR(255),
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tests (
  id INT,
  test VARCHAR(255),
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE samplesTests (
  sampleId INT,
  testId INT,
  primary key (sampleId, testId),
  INDEX(testId, sampleId)
  // foreign on sampleId
  // foreign on testID
);
```

The way your data would output:
samplesTests:

```
| SAMPLEID | TESTID   |
|----------|----------|
|  0       | T0       |
|  0       | T1       |
|  1       | T0       |
|  1       | T2       |
|  2       | T3       |
|  2       | T4       |
|  2       | T5       |
```

And since now the table is composed of 2 primary key, each pair of keys can only exist once, so there can be only 1 row with id "0" and tests "T0". That way a sample can have multiple tests and a test can be "linked" to multiple samples.

Comment: Sometimes, you need to start with a testId and find the sample(s).  I added a secondary index to make that optimal.